# Adjust JQuery Slider min/max

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I am using the jQuery dual slider from here:

http://hmelyoff.github.com/jslider/

however, that doesn't seem to allow me to reinitialize/change the min/max (from/to in this case) of the slider after I get back some new data through ajax. Does anyone know of a visually appealing dual slider that allows me to do so? Otherwise I'd probably have to end up modifying the slider above, and I am hoping not to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the jQuery UI Slider? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range

```
Get or set the max option, after init.

//getter
var max = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "max", 7 );
```

And

```
Get or set the min option, after init.

//getter
var min = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "min" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "min", -7 );
```